# No Connection String called "...Entities" could be found in the application file but it is there?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, entity-framework-6, connection-string

Hi I am receiving an error (No Connection String called "BuildingSettingsEntities" could be found in the application file) on this line of xaml:

```
 d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=viewModel:BuilderViewModel, 
 IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
```

However I added this connection string to my app.config as shown below:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="BuildingSettingsEntities" 
connectionString="metadata=res://*/BuildingSettingsModel.csdl|res://*/BuildingSettingsModel.ssdl|res://*/BuildingSettingsModel.msl;
provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
provider connection string=&quot;
data source=mrdk.database.windows.net,1433;
initial catalog=BuildingSettings;
persist security info=True;
user id=test;
password=testingpassword1234;
MultipleActiveResultSets=True;
App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out why this is happening so any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's because you have an **s** in your connection string name `BuildingSettingsEntities` in the `app.config`. The error is pointing out the name as `BuildingSettingEntities` without an **s**. If you change it then it should work as expected

Comment: Nice catch - those kinds of bugs are sometimes the hardest to find.

Comment: I completely agree with you.. and it's even worse when you realise it's such a small mistake

Comment: Apologies the my code was wrong i altered it as its work code (in my contract that I cannot fully paste working code), in the actual code they are both the same and spelt correctly. I will alter the question to correct this. Apologies for the misdirection